# TCL output with space

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have 5 different variable coming from different if and loop statements, when I use "put" to take output into text file all characters and digits are altogether like this : `alphaclass112098voip`. where

```
variables: name = alpha

category = class1

number = 12098

service = voip
```

I want output in file as like this with spaces on same line.

```
Alpha class1 12098 voip

Beta class1 12093 DHCP SIP
```

Also at certain point I want to through delimiters for future purposes.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is to construct a Tcl list that represents the record. You can do this piecemeal with `lappend`, or all at once with `list`. Or mix them.

```
foreach name $names category $categories number $numbers service $services {
    set record [list $name $category]
    lappend record $number
    lappend record $service
    puts $record
}
```

This shows the record for each line in a format that Tcl finds easy to parse (you'll see what I mean if you have a name with a space in it). To use a delimiter to separate the values instead, the `join` command is very useful:

```
    puts [join $record $delimiter]
```

The default delimiter is space, but try a `:` instead to see how it works.

---

If you're generating a CSV file, do use the [`csv` package](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) in Tcllib. It handles the tricky edge-cases (e.g., embedded commas) for you.